# Why does HTTP/2 have more latency over 3g?

Tags: networking, http, 3g

I'm thinking about transitioning to the new [HTTP/2 protocol](https://http2.github.io/), but a doubt has arisen.

For a thing HTTP/2 advocates latency reduction, but I'm seeing the opposite really. When I load the [Akamai demo](https://http2.akamai.com/demo) it shows less load time for HTTP/2, but latency increases in the range of 50-300%.

HTTP/1 left and HTTP/2 right.

[image: Akamai demo page]

Does it have to do with 3g at all? And if so why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 3g (and other wireless internets) will rise the ping.
Whether you are using HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 . Try to test it with cable internet .

Comment: Yes, I know the ping latency is like 50-300ms, but why does HTTP/2 have higher latency than the former?

Comment: I think its a bug. test it with cable network, if you had not this problem then its a bug. Or maybe the problem is with the 3g network since this protocol is new.

Comment: I will do so this evening when I have access to it and come back to report.

Comment: Over cable at the first try I got: 
HTTP/1.1
Latency: 1ms Image load time: 2.69s ------ 
HTTP/2
Latency: 7ms Image load time: 1.57s ------ ...but after reloading the page I also got the latencies the other way around so this probably depends on actual load and selection of the servers from the farm.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of 3G's large latency fluctuations "even in the same location at around the same time" [[relevant blog post](http://www.webperformancetoday.com/2011/10/26/interesting-findings-3g-mobile-performance-is-up-to-10x-slower-than-throttled-broadband-service/)]. Also, see [relevant book snippet](https://books.google.com/books?id=QXmBCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1427&ots=kq21avwD84&dq=3g%20latency%20variance&pg=PA1427#v=onepage&q=3g%20latency%20variance&f=false).